# Как установить размер input в зависимости от ширины ячейки в таблице bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Пользуюсь бутстрапом 4. У меня есть след. таблица:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Дата</th>
                <th>Остаток</th>
                <th>Выкуп зол.</th>
                <th>%</th>
                <th>Из офиса</th>
                <th>Залог зол.</th>
                <th>Скупка</th>
                <th>Остаток</th>
                <th>Офис</th>
                <th>Люди</th>
                <th>Новые</th>
                <th>Вес</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <form>
        <tr class="align-val-center">

            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="21.03.2018"/></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>27050</td>
            <td>11077</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>36850</td>
            <td>21080</td>
            <td>20197</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>15.62</td>

            <td align="center">
                <div class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-size:13px" role="button"><i class="far fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </form>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Выглядит она вот так, если нету внутри td input:

[image: Таблица без инпута]

Мне необходимо в каждую ячейку добавить инпут. Как только я это делаю колонка расширяется.

[image: Таблица с инпутом]

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, что бы таблица сохранила свои размеры как на скрине 1, но при этом инпут расширялся на 100% длинны родителя.

Я пробовал применять стили типа:

```
td
    input.form-control
        width: 100% !important
        box-sizing: border-box !important
```

Но это не дает результата. Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос

Comment: Вот ссылка на CodePen, та же история: https://codepen.io/WhoIsDT/pen/rdyoRQ

Comment: Есть костыль: нужно задать min-width и max-width для input, например 120px

Comment: Да, так и решил уже...

Comment: На JavaScript получить текущую ширину и в инпут добавить её как фиксированную.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин такие манипуляции на стороне клиента разве не приведут к подергиваниям интерфейса?

Comment: js решение не катит, так как придется постоянно реагировать на ресайз. Таблица то резиновая

Comment: @yolosora ну как я понял инпут добавляется на стороне клиента в скрипте... так почему бы ему и ширину фиксированной не задать. Насчёт подёргиваний не знаю, надо пробовать, если есть думать как исправить.

Comment: @WhoIsDT возможно как-то влияют стили bootstarp инпута, попробуйте сделать не бутстраповский, а обычный, если получится, то смотрите что именно в bootstrap портит стиль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать вот такой костыль

`<input class="form-control" size="1" type="text" value="21.03.2018"/>`

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо